# Error when using input file

Tags: c++, file, input

So here is a void function I wrote, but `<<` is showing up red and won't run the program. This is the first time I've had this problem, what do I do? This is done in C++, and I am using visual studio for my compiler.

```
    void readData() //reading the function
{
    ifstream inputfile;
    inputfile.open("student.txt"); //open file for the students grades and names
for (int count = 0; count<20; count++)
    {
        inputfile **>>** st[count].studentFName >> st[count].studentLName; //reading each field
        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
            inputfile >> st[count].test_score[i]; //reading each score
    }
    inputfile.close(); //close the file
    cout << " Reading of the file was completed!" <<endl;
}
```

The part that is `**>>**` is where my error is happening. It says it's not part of string?.

Comment: Please post definition, in your question, of `st[]`.

Comment: my apologies, it is st is to be student, so its student count

Comment: This is not related to your problem, but it is better to not use explicit `open` and `close` calls with `ifstream`. Instead, use RAII: `ifstream inputfile("student.txt")`.

Comment: and how would that make the file open or close?

Comment: The stream does it for you. `ifstream`'s constructor opens the file and the destructor closes it when inputfile passes out of scope..

Comment: So my code has stopped working when i changed that, could I show you what I did and maybe you can see why?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably missing an `#include`. I suspect it's `<istream>`.

Comment: I added that in but nope thats not the solution, let me post my code now and see if anyone can figure it out.. I'm lost

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <string> 
#include <istream>
using namespace std;

struct StudentType
{
    string studentFName;
    string studentLName;
    int test_score[5];
    char score;  //naming my variables
};

struct StudentType stu[20]; //you cannot enter more than 20 students with grades

void data() //reading the void function
{
    ifstream inputfile;
    ifstream inputfile("student.txt"); //open file for the students grades and names
    for (int count = 0; count<20; count++)
    {
        inputfile >> stu[count].studentFName >> stu[count].studentLName; //reading each field
        for (int i = 0; i<5; i++)
            inputfile >> stu[count].test_score[i]; //reading each score
    }
    ifstream inputfile("student.txt"); //close the file
    cout << " Reading of the file was completed!" << endl;
}

void studentGrade()
{
    ofstream outputfile;
    outputfile.open("output.txt"); //Open file for writing
    int total[20];
    for (int i = 0; i<20; i++) //20 records
    {
        total[i] = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++) //calculating scores
            total[i] += stu[i].test_score[j];
        cout << " Totals : " << total[i] << endl;
        if ((total[i] / 5) >= 90) //finding of grades
            stu[i].score = 'A';
        else if ((total[i] / 5) >= 80)
            stu[i].score = 'B';
        else if ((total[i] / 5) >= 70)
            stu[i].score = 'C';
        else
            stu[i].score = 'D';
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<20; i++) //This will be for entering in 20 different students and grades
    {
        outputfile << stu[i].studentFName << "  " << stu[i].studentLName << " "; //the data for the file
        for (int j = 0; j<5; j++) //writing of 05 scores
            outputfile << "  " << stu[i].test_score[j];
        outputfile << "  " << stu[i].score << endl; //this will be the grades for the students
    }
    outputfile.close(); //closing the file

    cout << " File content is stored in output.txt" << endl;
}
int main()
{
    cout << " Welcome to my file!" << endl;
    data();
    studentGrade();
    cout << "Thank you for using my program! " << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably edit your original question to include this, rather than posting it as an answer.

Comment: Why are you redefining `inpufile` on 3 different occasions in the `data` function? That code surely won't compile, apart from the original error you had

Comment: well someone else told me that was one of the problems, so I shouldn't have that than? And sorry I'm still learning how this works, its not the answer because its not working.